# Print array with checkboxes, want the values

Tags: php, arrays, magento, checkbox

I have an array where i have Checkboxes in.

Each category of checkboxes contains 4 options, and you can choose as many as you want to. I dont know how to get the value without serializing. Can anybody help me?

My array looks like this serialized:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"6";i:2;s:1:"7";i:3;s:1:"8";}
```

So i only want the values between the " " tags, how can i get this?

Comment: Why not use `unserialize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `unserialize`.

If not, then try this:

```
$str = 'a:4:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"6";i:2;s:1:"7";i:3;s:1:"8";}';
preg_match_all(  '/"(\d+)"/', $str, $matches );

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly when i do this:

$sammensat = "".print_r($matches[1])."";

it only sends me the number 1

Comment: `$matches[1]` is an array and you are trying to assign it to a string, so it won't work. Either use `implode` or get all values from array before assigning it to a string.

Comment: I dont think i got this all right.

$str = 'a:4:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"6";i:2;s:1:"7";i:3;s:1:"8";}';
preg_match_all(  '/"(\d+)"/', $str, $matches );
$sep = implode(",", $matches);
$string = "".$sep."";

cause it returns array, array

Comment: IN array it looks like this Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 )

Comment: You have to do `$sep = implode(",", $matches[1]);`

Comment: You saved me! works just perfectly. God i hate arrays... and love them at the same time

Answer (score 0):

you can try with unserialize()

```
$org=unserialize($array)
var_export()
```